# How to pass const to multiple components / Spliting React-Redux-Router files

Tags: html, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am creating a Spotify app with its API. I want 4 views (like '/', 'nowPlaying', 'favouriteArtists', 'favouriteSongs').

I need to `setAccessToken` for using functions like `getMyCurrentPlaybackState()` in every new page, right?. Idk if I need to `if(params.access_token){spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(params.access_token)}` in every container that will use functions like `getMyCurrentPlaybackState()`. I was thinking of creating a Spotify.jsx container that handle the store of the Spotify Object (which is used in the token and in every container that use spotify functions). But with this Spotify.jsx i don't know either if it is a good approach nor how to `connect` its needed `spotifyWebApi` const to every container file and token file.

For better understanding of my idea: I would create a Token.jsx that has `getHashParams()` and a Playing.jsx that has `getNowPlaying()`. Every one needs the `spotifyWebApi` const.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';

const spotifyWebApi = new Spotify();

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    const params = this.getHashParams(); 
    this.state = { 
      loggedIn: params.access_token ? true : false,
      nowPlaying: {
        name: 'Not Checked',
        image: ''
      }
    }
    if (params.access_token){ 
      spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(params.access_token) 
    }

  }
  getHashParams() {
    var hashParams = {};
    var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
        q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
       hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
    }
    return hashParams;
  }
  getNowPlaying(){
    spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
      .then((response) => { 
        this.setState({
          nowPlaying: {
            name: response.item.name,
            image: response.item.album.images[0].url
          }
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title mentions Redux, but I don't see your code utilizing it. With Redux, you could get the access_token and then store it in state. This will allow you to use it in any Redux connected component.

Also, with Redux, you can use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) (or similar) middleware that will allow you to use Redux actions to call an API. So then you would just write the different API calls as Redux actions, which would allow you to call them from any component, and have the results added to your Redux store (which again, can be used in any Redux connected component).

So, for example, your `getNowPlaying()` function could be an action looking something like this:

```
function getNowPlaying() {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    // get the token and init the api
    const access_token = getState().spotify.access_token
    spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(access_token) 

    return spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState().then((response) => { 
        dispatch({
          type: 'SET_NOW_PLAYING',
          name: response.item.name,
          image: response.item.album.images[0].url
        })
      })
  }
}
```

Note: You'll need to configure the [Redux reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) for "spotify" (or however you want to structure your store) to store the data you need.

So, you could then call getNowPlaying() from any component. It stores the results in the redux store, which you could also use from any connected component. And you can use the same technique of getting the access_token from the store when needed in the actions.

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use Redux, you could provide context values to all child components, using [React's Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) features. You could do this with that token that each component would need in your setup. But Redux, in my opinion, is the better option for you here.

Comment: Thank you! Isn't `const access_token = getState().spotify.access_token` unnecesary? Can't I simply use `spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(getState().spotify.access_token)`. Why would I reserve memory for that?

Comment: Yep, I was just trying to make it clear what I was doing there, but you can do it with that one-liner as well. Glad it helped!

Comment: how do I obtain the new name and image from an external presentational component? idk if need to `connect` image and name to the component and process the dispatch action with a reducer. How do I use the name and image inside the component?

Comment: If it's a presentational component that you want to keep "dumb", get those in the parent "smart" or connected component and pass them as props to the child component. But if the presentational component stands by itself and not one of a list of components that will update often, you can just connect it directly. Just know that a connected component will update and re-render if those state fields you've mapped in change. I hope I made sense there and that it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing this const to other components, I would create a `SpotifyUtils.jsx` and inside it declare the const. And in this helper file I would export functions so other components can use them.
For example:

```
import Spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';

const spotifyWebApi = new Spotify();
let token = null

export function isLoggedIn() {
  return !!token
}

export function setAccessToke(_token) {
  token = _token;
  spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(_token);
}

export function getNowPlaying(){
  return spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
    .then((response) => { 
      return {
        name: response.item.name,
        image: response.item.album.images[0].url
      }
    })
}
```

So that in the components you can use them like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  isLoggedIn,
  setAccessToken,
  getNowPlaying,
} from 'helpers/SpotifyUtils'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super(); 
    this.state = { 
      loggedIn: isLoggedIn(),
      nowPlaying: {
        name: 'Not Checked',
        image: ''
      }
  }

getHashParams() {
  var hashParams = {};
  var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
    q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
  while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
     hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
  }
  return hashParams;
}

componentDidMount() {
  if (!this.state.loggedIn) {
    const params = this.getHashParams();
    if (params.access_token) {
      setAccessToken(params.access_token)
      getNowPlaying()
      .then(nowPlaying => this.setState({ nowPlaying }))
    }
  }
}
}
```

This will enable your spotifyWebApi const to be reused in any component you import the helper functions. I am particularly found of this pattern, creating `utils` or `helpers` in a generic fashion so that you can reuse code easily. Also if spotify Web Api releases a breaking change, your refactor will be easier because you will only need to refactor the `SpotifyUtils.jsx` file since it will be the only file using `import Spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js'`

Comment: Thank you! But... what is `!!token`?

Comment: It was suposed to be params.access_token that was in your example